# How to alter navbar styling on menu toggle click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the bootstrap 3 inverse navbar. When the toggle button is clicked, i want to remove the existing background image(since this clashes with the toggle layout). However, i want to restore the background image when the toggle is collapsed.

This is the current HTML and CSS;

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" onclick="menuclick()">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: white;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: black;
}


.navbar.navbar-inverse {
    background: url('../images/banner.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 1% 0 1% 0;
}
```

I have tried to use the following approach:
Onlclick -> find the current background style.
if style = image, remove style
else add image back

I have tried the following Javascript to try and access the navbar background-image but it seems that the background node within the style node is empty:

```
function menuclick() {
    var nav = document.getElementById('navbar');
}
```

Please let me know if you have any ideas how this can be achieved

Comment: haven't played much with the collapsible navbar, but by watching the element inspector in chrome dev tools while I toggle one in and out, I can see that, when collapsed, the `.navbar-collapse` is also given a class of `.in` -- what about simply using CSS? Styling `.navbar-collapse` one way, then styling `.navbar-collapse.in` another?

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 3 collapse class exposes a few events for hooking into collapse functionality.

```
show.bs.collapse --> fires immediately when the show instance method is called.
shown.bs.collapse --> fires when a collapse element has been made visible to     the user (CSS transitions to completes before execution).
hide.bs.collapse --> fires immediately when the hide method has been called. 
hidden.bs.collapse --> fires when a collapse element has been hidden from the user (CSS transitions to complete  before execution).
```

Example

```
$('#navbar').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
  // restore the existing background image
});


$('#navbar').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
      // remove the existing background image
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using classes to add/remove styles. In other words, when your toggle button is clicked, you toggle a class on the nav element.

Here is a proof of concept:

[View Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xcpgd21g/)

```
<nav>
  <button>Menu</button>
</nav>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').on('click',function() {
    $('nav').toggleClass('navbar-inverse');
  });
});
```

Now, it sounds like you want to remove that inverse class when the navbar is closed, which may not involve another button click. So, you cannot only rely on this toggle when the menu button is clicked. You will also need to detect when the navbar closes, and remove the inverse class appropriately.

You should be able to leverage the class that Bootstrap is adding/removing for the navbar functionality to add/remove the styling you want.

Answer (score 0):

As far as for the currently set image, you can use
`$('#navbar').css('background-image')` to get the currently set image or you can pass in a second argument to update the current `background-image` style.

Moreover I'd suggest to go with Yasir's suggestion to get the collapse event.

Here's a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jgcswfg1/) for your code.